# Error adding plugin plugin.google.maps.CordovaGoogleMaps

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm using Ionic 4 and I'm trying to implement google maps using [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps). Its a cordova plugin but I'm trying to run with capacitor. It works on browser, but every time I run it on android device it keeps closing the app and on the logs

> aused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "plugin.google.maps.CordovaGoogleMaps" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/io.ionic.starter-ajxCliINX8_ISu_gkqulJg==/base.apk", zip
>   file
>
> Error adding plugin plugin.google.maps.CordovaGoogleMaps.

Does anybody knows this issue, been searching since yesterday, unlucky.

Comment: do you installed https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Comment: @ORBIT Yea I installed it. But I was wondering about compatibility cause I used capacitor run android or it should only work on cordova?